# Regex match occurrences only after character sequence

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to find all the characters after w's that occur in this string, but only the ones after `foo`

```
edward woodward foo edward woodward
```

`/(?<=w)./g` gives me 6 matches

edw**a**rd w**o**odw**a**rd foo edw**a**rd w**o**odw**a**rd

I only want the 3 matches that occur after `foo`.  How would I modify the regex to narrow the scope of the search?

Comment: Use [`(?:\bfoo\b|\G(?!^))[^w]*w\K.`](https://regex101.com/r/Z9hdRm/1) in PCRE. What is your regex engine? In .NET, it is simpler, [`(?<=\bfoo\b.*?)(?<=w).`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbfoo%5cb.*%3f%29%28%3f%3c%3dw%29.&i=edward+woodward+foo+edward+woodward)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew PCRE.  Your regex works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex with a PCRE engine:

```
(?:\bfoo\b|\G(?!^))[^w]*w\K.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9hdRm/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\bfoo\b|\G(?!^))` - either a whole word `foo` (`\bfoo\b`) or (`|`) the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`)
- `[^w]*` - any 0+ chars other than `w`
- `w` - a `w` char
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `.` - any char (other than line break chars, if you need to match them with `.` add `(?s)` at the pattern start or replace `.` with `(?s:.)`)